# Java Generic Classes, how to define constructor for possible Parameter types

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to define a Java class which could be used for generic types, but I want to define the constructors for possible parameter types like Character, or an object type I can manually define.

The class I am trying to create is called:

```
public class Repeated<T> implements Pict {

private T[][] elements;

private double scale;

public Repeated(T[][] elems) {
    elements = elems;
}
}
```

So I want to add a  constructor that adds a Character Array and does something specific if only T is the Type Character. Is it possible? Or should I make this an Interface, then implement it later?

Comment: It's not possible with constructors, but it may well be possible if you use static factory methods instead!

Comment: Due to type erasure, this isn't possible. Also, remember the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle - if you really need generics, I'd look at what @Paul Bellora has described, otherwise leave it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I want to add a constructor that adds a Character Array and does
>   something specific if only T is the Type Character

Sounds like a good case for polymorphism:

```
public class RepeatedChars extends Repeated<Character> {

    public RepeatedChars(Character[][] chars) {
        super(chars);
        //do special stuff
    }

    //other character-specific logic if applicable
}
```

You could even hide this class as an implementation detail:

```
public class Repeated<T> implements Pict {

    ...

    private static class RepeatedChars extends Repeated<Character> {
        //see above
    }

    public static Repeated<Character> makeForChars(Character[][] chars) {
        return new RepeatedChars(chars);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to do this with factory methods, you don't need subclasses. Just define a (most likely private) constructor `Repeated(T[][] elems, boolean isCharsFlag)`. The factory methods can then pass the appropriate flag value to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this:

```
public Repeated(T[][] elems) {
    elements = elems;
    boolean isCharacterArrayArray = false;
    if (elems != null) {
        for (T[] elt : elems) {
            if (elt != null && elt.length > 0) {
                isCharacterArrayArray = elt[0] instanceof Character;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isCharacterArrayArray) {
        // received a Character[][]
    }
}
```

However, because of type erasure, I don't think you can distinguish these calls:

```
new Repeated((Character[][]) null);
new Repeated((Integer[][]) null);
```

without passing some sort of explicit class argument.

**EDIT** With a class argument, it all becomes much simpler:

```
public Repeated(T[][] elems, Class<T> cls) {
    elements = elems;
    if (cls.equals(Character.class)) {
        // passed a Character[][]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not crazy about your solution, but you could just use [`Class.getComponentType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType\(\)) - that would account for empty arrays.

Comment: @PaulBellora - Excellent idea. It still wouldn't work for `null` arrays, though, since there's no object there to call `getClass()` on. I don't like my solution, either; passing a `Class` object fixes everything, though.